# Create data extension > define location

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Does anyone know how to define the location for the data extension when using SOAP api to create a data extension?

Answer (score 3):

You can use it by `<CategoryID>` tag in SOAP to add it in folder. If you use Inspect (Open in Chrome > Right click > Inspect > click on the data extension folder) on the category Id will be the parent folder ID.

[image]

Below can be same example for SOAP UI to create a data extension in a folder:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <par:CreateRequest>
            <par:Options/>
            <par:Objects
                    xsi:type="par:DataExtension">
                <par:Client>
                    <par:ClientID>MID</par:ClientID>
                </par:Client>
                <par:CategoryID>Folder ID</par:CategoryID>
                <par:ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
                <par:ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                <par:Name>Data Extension Name</par:Name>
                <par:Description>Data Extension Description</par:Description>
                <par:IsSendable>false</par:IsSendable>
            <par:IsTestable>false</par:IsTestable>
            <par:DataRetentionPeriodLength>48</par:DataRetentionPeriodLength>
            <par:DataRetentionPeriod>Days</par:DataRetentionPeriod>
            <par:RowBasedRetention>false</par:RowBasedRetention>
            <par:ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport>true</par:ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport>
            <par:DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod>false</par:DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod>
                <par:Fields>
                <par:Field>
                    <par:CustomerKey>PE_ID</par:CustomerKey>
                    <par:Name>PE_ID</par:Name>
                    <par:Description>PE_ID</par:Description>
                    <par:IsPrimaryKey>true</par:IsPrimaryKey>
                    <par:MaxLength>100</par:MaxLength>
                    <par:FieldType>Text</par:FieldType>
                    <par:DefaultValue></par:DefaultValue>
                    <par:IsRequired>true</par:IsRequired>
                </par:Field>
                </par:Fields>
            </par:Objects>
        </par:CreateRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is about creating a data extension folder, but the OP is asking about adding a Data Extension into a specific folder. Great info, but it is not what the question is about. Please adjust it to reflect what is being asked.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington for rightly pointing out. Am sorry, I overlooked the question. I have updated my answer now.

Comment: Thanks @NaveenVM, this worked.

Comment: You are welcme @WillemRuys.! Am glad that it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

We use ssjs to create Data Extension and we use the property CategoryID on the data extension object. We set the value to a static value of the folder in which we wish to create the data extension. When you hover over your folder, you will see the id at the bottom. See below. I have not worked with SOAP API, but I believe the underlying object and property remains the same. Hope this helps :)

[image]