# Create in, or Move a Data Extension to the Salesforce Data Extensions folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I tried using the SOAP API to create a data extension and set the CategoryID to the Salesforce Data Extensions folder, but I get this error:

"Unable to save data extension into a non-data extension category. The category provided was of type salesforcedataextension."

I opened a case with support who also said there is no SalesforceDataExtension object, allowing me to create one.

So I also tried to first create a data extension in the regular data extensions folder, then use InvokeUpdate to change the CategoryID, but that gave the same error. Has anyone found a way to do this? It seems the SOAP api is mostly concerned with adding columns/rows, not changing DE properties. Hoping there is something new that someone has discovered.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Garek , You can do it in a single call on create request itself by using category ID. Hope this helps - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306090/create-data-extension-define-location/306098#306098

Comment: @NaveenVM your post is not specific to the Salesforce Data Extensions folder.

Comment: Ya I just saw that. I guess its still not yet possible to my knowledge. You can add the data extension in a normal folder via SOAP API and move the data extension to salesforce data extension folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NaveenVM... I was really hoping for a programmatic way to do it